# How to convert column to rows in pandas?

Tags: pandas, pivot, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a dataframe:

```
user_id    product_name
0001       a
0001       b
0001       c
0002       b
0003       a
0003       c
0003       d
```

I want product_name column convert to this:

```
user_id    A    B    C    D
0001       a    b    c    NaN
0002       NaN  b    NaN  NaN
0003       a    NaN  c    d
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all we'll create a duplicate column of `product_name` let's name it  `product_name_extra` we will use this column later

```
df['product_name_extra'] = df.product_name
Out[223]:
user_id      product_name   product_name_extra
1                  a                a
1                  b                b
1                  c                c
2                  b                b
3                  a                a
3                  c                c
3                  d                d
```

then pivoting the edited data frame , check this [pivot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) if you want to get more information about pivoting

```
df_pivot = df.pivot(index='user_id' , columns='product_name' , values='product_name_extra')
Out[222]:
product_name    a   b   c   d
user_id             
1               a   b   c   NaN
2               NaN b   NaN NaN
3               a   NaN c   d
```

then finally rename your columns

```
df_pivot.rename(columns=str.upper)
Out[225]:
product_name    A   B   C   D
user_id             
1               a   b   c   NaN
2               NaN b   NaN NaN
3               a   NaN c   d
```

Comment: Can you post a textual explanation (not only inline comments)

Comment: sure I've updated my answer let me know if you still need further explanation